# Как повернуть матрицу на 90 градусов с разной размерностью?

Tags: c#, матрицы

Никак не могу сообразить, как повернуть матрицу с разной размерностью?

Пытался вот так, но при смене ширины или высоты, все ломается.

```
newMatrix = new bool[h, w];
for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
    {
        newMatrix [h - 1 - j, i] = oldMatrix[i, j];
    }
}
```

Comment: если бы она была квадратной, то смоглы бы. инасче надо создавать новую матрицу

Comment: У вас нормальный алгоритм вроде, что конкретно ломается?

Comment: ошибка выхода за рамки массива. Все хорошо работает только для квадратных матриц

Comment: тут либо искусственно делать ее квадратной, либо создавать новую. советую 2 вариант

Comment: Приведите весь код. По приведенному фрагменту проблем с `newMatrix` не видно. Покажите как создаете `oldMatrix`

Comment: А зачем вам ее поворачивать? Просто читайте ее в другом направлении. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам пример поворота двумерного массива на 90 градусов по и против часовой стрелке

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] array = new int[6, 5] {
                                        { 1,2,3,4 ,5},
                                        { 5,6,7,8,6 },
                                        { 9,0,1,2 ,7},
                                        { 3,4,5,6,8 },
                                        { 3,4,5,6,8 },
                                        { 3,4,5,6,8 }
                                      };         
        for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int k= 0; k < array.GetLength(1); k++)
            {
                Console.Write(array[i,k]+ " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Rotate Matrix Clockwise");
        int[,] rotated = RotateMatrixClockwise(array);
        for (int i = 0; i < rotated.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < rotated.GetLength(1); k++)
            {
                Console.Write(rotated[i, k]+ " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Rotate Matrix  AntiClockwise");
        int[,] rotated1 = RotateMatrixAntiClockwise(array);
        for (int i = 0; i < rotated1.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < rotated1.GetLength(1); k++)
            {
                Console.Write(rotated1[i, k]+ " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
 public static int[,] RotateMatrixClockwise(int[,] oldMatrix)
    {
        int[,] newMatrix = new int[oldMatrix.GetLength(1), oldMatrix.GetLength(0)];
        int newColumn, newRow = 0;
        for (int oldColumn = oldMatrix.GetLength(1) - 1; oldColumn >= 0; oldColumn--)
        {
            newColumn = 0;
            for (int oldRow = 0; oldRow < oldMatrix.GetLength(0); oldRow++)
            {
                newMatrix[newRow, newColumn] = oldMatrix[oldRow, oldColumn];
                newColumn++;
            }
            newRow++;
        }
        return newMatrix;
    }
    public static int[,] RotateMatrixAntiClockwise(int[,] oldMatrix)
    {
        int[,] newMatrix = new int[oldMatrix.GetLength(1), oldMatrix.GetLength(0)];
        int newColumn, newRow = 0;
        for (int oldColumn = 0; oldColumn < oldMatrix.GetLength(0) - 1; oldColumn++)
        {
            newColumn = 0;
            for (int oldRow = oldMatrix.GetLength(1) ; oldRow >=0 ; oldRow--)
            {
                newMatrix[newRow, newColumn] = oldMatrix[oldRow, oldColumn];
                newColumn++;
            }
            newRow++;
        }
        return newMatrix;
    }
```

Comment: 1) Название ваших методов больше дезориентирует, чем что-то объясняет, например, "counter clockwise" - переводится как "против часовой стрелки", тогда как перевести ваш метод "counter anti clockwise"?


2) Вынесите вывод массива в отдельный метод, а не 3 раза его повторяйте.

3) Добавите разделить между элементами массива, при выводе на экран. Например, `onsole.Write(array[i,k] + " ");`

Comment: @Jagailo  я так понял красивый вывод еще важнее логики?

Comment: Красивый - это когда между элементами `,`, а в конце строчки `.`. Вывод массива должен быть читабельным, хоть какой-никакой разделитель должен быть. Про логику я ничего не говорил, поворачивает нормально.

Comment: @Jagailo спасибо за правку но я здесь думал написать правильную логику а не сделать красивый вывод тем более что написанные функции можно употреблять не только в консольных программ но где угодно и там вывод зависит от разработчика кому как нравиться ;) главное увидеть правильный результат

Answer (score 1):

Обычно преобразование структур типа матрицы занимает много ресурсов. Поэтому лучше их не "крутить", а преобразовывать индексы, по которым вы получаете доступ к полям матрицы. Что-то, типа такого:

```
class Matrix2D
{
    public decimal this[uint colIndex, uint rowIndex]
    {
        get
        {
            _rotateIndex(ref colIndex, ref rowIndex);
            return _matrix[colIndex, rowIndex];
        }
        set
        {
            _rotateIndex(ref colIndex, ref rowIndex);
            _matrix[colIndex, rowIndex] = value;
        }
    }

    private void _rotateIndex(ref uint c, ref uint r)
    {
        if (c >= Width || r >= Height) throw new ArgumentException("Index out of range");

        uint tmpC = c;
        uint tmpR = r;

        switch (_rotate)
        {
            case 0:
            default:
                break;
            case 1:
                c = tmpR;
                r = Width - 1 - tmpC;
                break;
            case 2:
                c = Width - 1 - tmpC;
                r = Height - 1 - tmpR;
                break;
            case 3:
                c = Height - 1 - tmpR;
                r = tmpC;
                break;
        }
    }        

    private decimal[,] _matrix;
    private uint _rotate = 0;

    private Matrix2D() { }
    public Matrix2D(uint width, uint height)
    {
        if (width == 0 || height == 0) throw new ArgumentNullException();

        this.Height = height;
        this.Width = width;

        _matrix = new decimal[width, height];
    }

    public uint Height { get; set; }
    public uint Width { get; set; }

    public void Rotate(uint frac) //угол деленый на 90 градусов
    {
        _rotate += frac;
        _rotate %= 4;
        if ((frac%2) != 0)
        {
            var tmp = Width;
            Width = Height;
            Height = tmp;
        }
    }


}
```